# iOS Beta Sign Up Not Working

Tags: apple-id, beta-seed-program

I sign in, and go to the sign up page. That's where I have to accept the terms. Everytime I click the accept button, it reverts back to the sign up page.

It's not taking me to the download profile page.

I'm on mobile safari iOS 9.3.3 and wondering if I can enroll from that device or if e signup process is broken?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. what browser version and OS are you using to sign in? Are you looking for help with your computer or perhaps looking for Apple's support department to check that your Apple ID password is correct?

Comment: I'm using 9.3.3, on my iPhone. I know my password is correct. I have a bug that everytime I click accept on the beta page. It reverts back to the signup page.